# How many IPCs does the USA receive in Axis & Allies Global?

Tags: axis-and-allies

In the combined global game for Axis & Allies: Europe 1940 and Axis & Allies: Pacific 1940, how much money does the USA receive before and after it is engaged in a war? Many references I've seen list the USA economy at 52 IPCs, but is this the starting economy?

I've also read that the USA is supposed to receive a boost of 30 IPCs when they are at war. Are these 30 IPCs in addition to money potentially gained from fulfilling national objectives, or does it simply mean the player is now eligible to receive up to 30 from national objectives?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that in the 1940 version of this game the USA starts with around 27 IPC's on the Pacific map and 35 on the Europe side, so a total of roughly 62(?, perhaps my numbers are wrong) as a STARTING income. Then they will have the 30 IPC's per turn added on once at war, which is their only national objective, so when they are at war, they will have an economy of exactly thirty IPC's more than what they gain from territories(convoy losses and extraneous circumstances aside), no more, no less from NO's. I do not own this version, so this is only my take on it.

Comment: 62 is wrong, it is supposed to be 52, according to [the rules](http://www.axisandallies.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Axis-Allies-Europe-1940-Second-Edition.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of the rules: at the start of the game, the players and countries IPC's are calculated by what territories they own. So at the start of the Global A&A game, add up all of the U.S.'s territories and that is there starting income. When they enter the war, they get an IPC boost of 30. That is how I understand it... hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the rules, page 34](http://www.axisandallies.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Axis-Allies-Europe-1940-Second-Edition.pdf), the US starts with 52 IPC both in treasury and income:

> The powers start with the following IPC income levels
>   and treasuries:
>
> Power  |
>   Starting Income
>
> (...)
>
> United States  52
>
> (...)

Answer (score 0):

In the global version, the U.S. pre-war points are as follows:

Eastern U.S., 20 points. 
Central U.S. 12 points.  
Western U.S. 17 points.  
Caribbean (Mexico, Central America, West Indies): 3 points.
Total, 52 points, which is the starting economy.

After the war begins, there are three bonuses:
Western U.S. intact, 40 points.
Central and Eastern U.S. intact, 20 points.
All three Caribbean territories in U.S. hands, 5 points.
Total bonuses: 65 points.
Sub Grand total:117 points.

There are also another 15 bonus points in the Pacific that the U.S. may or may not be able to get. 
Philippines: 5 points. 
Holding both Alaska and Mexic: 5 points.
Holding four island chains: 5 points.
Grand total: 132 points.

Some versions of the rules confuse the issue by saying only 30 points bonus for the Western U.S. in Axis and Allies Pacific, but this [map](https://www.axisandallies.org/p/image_axisallies_pacific_1940_map/) makes it clear that it's 40. That is, it shows 10 IPCs for the U.S. prewar, and 50 IPCs (an addition of 40), after war begins.